# Is $x^5-10x^3+20x= 8.58368$ solvable?

Tags: quintics

This quintic has 5 real [**roots**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E5-10x%5E3%2B20x%3D8.58368), how do we find out if it is solvable and ,in that case, how to solve it? Is there a generally valid numeric approach?

Comment: "a generally valid numeric approach" Newton's method works for most polynomials. I'm sure there are better tools more specialised for polynomials. As for solvability, is $8.58368$ exact, or rounded from some square root or something? It seems a little out of place here.

Comment: Define `solvable`. Do you mean closed form roots (no), number of real roots (yes), range of RHS such that it has $5$ real roots (yes), or ...?

Comment: If 2.8 is an exact root, then you can divide the original equation $x^{5}-10x^{3}+20x-8.58368$ by $x-2.8$ and solve the quartic equation.

Answer (score 3):

In general, a quintic cannot be solved exatly by radicals.
But substiture $x\leftarrow y/10$ to arrive at
$$y^5-1000 y^3+200000y = 858368$$
First, we look for rational solutions, which must be among the divisors of $858368$. After finitely many trials, we find $y=28$ ($x=2.8$).
The remaining solutions hide in
$$ y^4 + 28y^3 - 216y^2 - 6048y + 3065600=0,$$
which unfortunately does not factor so easily. While [quartics *are* solvable by radicals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuarticEquation.html), one would usually still prefer to resort to numerical methods to tackle them (as in, usually a quite exact numerical value helps you more than an extremely convoluted exact expression).

Comment: It is amazing to see how "simple" are the roots using radicals. May be, you could add them to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Let $x=a\sin t$

$$\dfrac{a^5}{16}=\dfrac{10a^3}{20}=\dfrac{20a}5$$

$\implies a^2=8,$

$$\implies x^5-10x^3+20x=\pm?\sin5t\le?$$ for real $x$

Comment: $$?$$ will be replaced by $$\dfrac{20\sqrt8}5=8\sqrt2>8.58368$$